# rspec / Devise / current_user - wrong user instance (controller spec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, controllers

I am using RSpec to test my nested controllers. I've signed in current_user (member in my case) and it is returning a different instance. Please see below:

Spec snippet:

```
before :each do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:member]
    @member = create(:member)
    sign_in @member
    @calendar = @member.calendars.create!({"name" => "test"}, Calendars::Native)
end

it "creates a new Event" do
    puts "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    puts @member
    puts @calendar
    puts @calendar.events.count
    puts "->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->-"

    post :create, {:native_id => @calendar.id, :event => valid_attributes}, valid_session

    puts "<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<"
    puts @member
    puts @calendar
    puts @calendar.events.count
    puts "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    expect {
      post :create, {:native_id => @calendar.to_param, :event => valid_attributes}, valid_session
    }.to change(@calendar.events, :count).by(1)  #Event, :count).by(1)
end
```

Controller Snippet

```
def create
    set_calendar
    @event = @calendar.events.build(event_params) 
    respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save
            puts "DID SAVE"
            puts @member
            puts @calendar
            puts @event

            format.html { redirect_to native_event_url(:native_id => @calendar.id, :id => @event.id), notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
    end
  end

  def set_calendar
       @member = current_member
       @calendar = @member.calendars.find(params[:native_id])
  end
```

Console output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#<Member:0x007fb5a6e4fda0>
#<Calendars::Native:0x007fb5a495bf58>
0
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->-
DID SAVE
#<Member:0x007fb5a49a1aa8>
#<Calendars::Native:0x007fb5a49a0810>
#<Event:0x007fb5a49b3eb0>
<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<
#<Member:0x007fb5a6e4fda0>
#<Calendars::Native:0x007fb5a495bf58>
0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see... Member objectId is different, which results in Rspec failing test because count doesn't change.

Any good suggestion? What's going on?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've forgot to say that I am using MongoId and Event is embedded in Calendars. Probably this is the reason why `Event, :count` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. You're just getting a bit confused.

When you first create `@member`, it gets stored in memory. It has object ID X. Then, in your actual controller, data is grabbed from the `current_user` method, and even though it's the same underlying data as `@member`, it's actually a different object in memory, so it has object ID Y. Your test is holding on to one object, your code on to another.

Instead of doing `puts @member`, try doing `puts @member.inspect`, or as a short cut, `p @member`. This will show you more information. You will probably get output like this instead:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX
#<Member id: 1, :name "John Doe">
->->->->->->
DID SAVE
#<Member id: 1, :name "John Doe">
<-<-<-<-<-<-
#<Member id: 1, :name "John Doe">
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

You'll see that the information about the user is the same. The fact that they are not the exact same object instance in memory doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks MrDanA... You are right... the ids are the same if I inspect them. Now the question is... why calendar.events.count doesn't change? Should I get a new calendar instance? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: When you call `@calendar.events` in the `expect`, I think it's caching that result in the `@calendar` object, so it doesn't see it change. Did it work when you expected just `Event, :count` to change? Also, try reloading `@calendar` with `@calendar.reload`.

Comment: No... `expect{...}.to change(Event, :count).by(1)` doesn't work either. I will try to reload calendar, but spec is starting to become ugly!! ;-)

Comment: I don't know about differences with Mongold. Another way (and in my opinion, better) to tackle this problem is after you send the request to create your object, check it explicitly. Try to find the Event, then check each of its attributes to make sure they were all saved.